# Using polymorphism instead of a conditional when the responsibility doesn't belong in the class

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism, solid-principles

Something I'm running into working on a very simple application that's part of a school project.

It's a very basic console based employee management system where you can add 4 types of employees (full time, part time, contract, seasonal, all with a couple different attributes.)

The problem I'm having is when displaying a menu for modifying a specific employee type.

Doing a switch statement on the employee type is obviously quite bad design, but adding "DisplayModificationMenu" to each employee class so that it can display its own menu also seems terrible, because displaying a menu doesn't seem like an appropriate responsibility for an employee object itself.

What's the best approach to solving this design issue? I have considered creating a Menu class and subtype every menu so each one can display itself, but even then I feel like a switch on the type would still occur somewhere to decide which menu to instantiate.

The workflow to modify an employee is select an employee by their ID, and then the correct menu for that employee type should display. So even with the subtyped menus, it seems you'd have to check the employee type before you knew which menu to instantiate.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think doing switch on type of an object is not a problem, as long as it is encapsulated, documented and understood properly.

In your case, you could make `DisplayMenuFactory`, that would accept abstract employee object and return abstract Menu class. And inside, it would switch based on employee type and return concrete Menu class for each type. And, if you end up having different factories, that have same switching mechanism, you can merge them together and this switching will happen always in single class. So responsibility for creating different UIs for different employees will be in this single class.

The second option is to have Employee class that has GetMenu method, that would return concrete Menu type for each employee type. But this is mixing model and UI, which is not something I think is acceptable in this case.

Comment: Thanks, the menu factory seems like the nicest solution to at least encapsulate it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

For me, there is not a "perfect way" for design. It depends on many things; project schedule, development technology, flexibility needing(s) etc.

But in your example, if you don't want to use switch statements in your menu generation routine, you can use decorator pattern. Think that a menu is kind of presentation of your employee object.

So;

1) Create a base class for menu decoration and add decorateMenu function into this class( MenuDecorator)

2) Create sub classes for each employee type ( MenuPartTimeEmployee, MenuFullTimeEmployee ... etc) and implement decorateMenu function for these classes. You can implement different behaviors for different employee classes.

3) If you don't have, create a base Employee class and extend employee sub classes from this class. Add decorator instance variable to base Employee class. For each Employee sub class assign suitable menu decorator class to menuDecorator instance variable. Such as for PartTimeEmployee class;

```
this.menuDecorator = new MenuPartTimeEmployee();
```

4) finally in your menu rendering routine;

```
// get target employee
employee = ...;
employee.menuDecorator.decorateMenu(); // Render menu for employee type
```

Advantage of this pattern is you are isolating your menu rendering code from the entity. Thus, you can implement different menu types behaviors for different operating systems, platforms (mobile, desktop etc.)

Comment: I don't think you are separating UI from the employee. Because in the end, the decorator must depend on some code that is UI related, so it can decorate it. Unless you want to abstract your whole UI behind it.

Comment: Of course decorator is ui related. Decorator aims to render suitable user interface objects for related entity. But at the end, you need a bridge between your entity classes and user interface. You can also use controller classes to separate ui and entities but even in this pattern, controller class must have instances of both entity and view.

Comment: I think the problem is, that abstracting UI sounds good in theory, but is hard and time-consuming in practice. You would need to re-implement your whole menu UI logic in this decorator. And this implementation would be only simple wrapper. I think the work needed doesn't justify not using switch.

Answer (score 0):

create a class called employee which has all the common attributes of the employees
all 4 classes should extend the class and you have basic methods which you can override if changes are needed or 
or if all menus are different for the employees create an interface  which all the 4 classes implement on they own way